# How to rename the text of grouped nodes after creating them in IDA?

Tags: ida

After I group nodes in IDA in the Graph View and name them, I can't change the name. I tried `Edit group text` button:

[image]

And `Rename` button:

[image]

I also tried anterior, posterior, normal comment and repeatable comment.

I tried it in 2 different versions of IDA: 7.2 and 7.6 and on 2 different unrelated executables.

Here's the video in real time which demonstrates the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o4U5.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I was checked on IDA v7.6.210427 and v7.7.211224 (MacOS).
I have not been able to reproduce your problem, everything works fine.
I recommend you check the installed plugins. It is possible that the behaviour you are describing is related to one of them.